# How to query Oracle tables using a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a single query where a column in one table returns data from another column. I have tried to do it using a subquery but with no luck. I would prefer to find a solution using subqueries rather than using 'JOIN' as I am still new to sql/oracle and can better understand subqueries...

The first query is:

```
SELECT MA_gardenermanager.managerID "senior gardener"
, MA_gardeners.gardenername
, MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID "Manages"
FROM MA_gardenermanager, MA_gardeners
where MA_gardeners.gardenerID = MA_gardenermanager.managerID
order by MA_gardenermanager.managerID
, MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID
;
```

This returns the following data:

```
senior gardener GARDENERNAME      Manages
4               Olivia Brown      1
4               Olivia Brown      5
5               Emily Williams    2
5               Emily Williams    3
```

The second query is:

```
select MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID
, MA_gardeners.gardenername "Manages"
from MA_gardeners, MA_gardenermanager
where MA_gardeners.gardenerID = MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID
;
```

This returns the following data:

```
GARDENERID  Manages
1           Oliver Smith
2           Jack Jones
3           Harry Taylor
5           Emily Williams
```

I am trying to combine the two queries above to produce this:

```
senior gardener GARDENERNAME      Manages
4               Olivia Brown      Oliver Smith
4               Olivia Brown      Emily Williams
5               Emily Williams    Jack Jones
5               Emily Williams    Harry Taylor
```

I've tried this but keep getting ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row:

```
SELECT MA_gardenermanager.managerID "senior gardener"
, MA_gardeners.gardenername
, MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID "manages"
, (select MA_gardeners.gardenername
from MA_gardeners, MA_gardenermanager
where MA_gardeners.gardenerID = MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID)
FROM MA_gardenermanager, MA_gardeners
where MA_gardeners.gardenerID = MA_gardenermanager.managerID
;
```

Is there a simple way I can combine the two queries by inserting the second query into the first one as a subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> " I would prefer to find a solution using subqueries rather than using
>   'JOIN' as I am still new to sql/oracle and can better understand
>   subqueries..."

Fnord.   A sub-query merely complicates what is actually a very simple thing.  All you need do is reference the `MA_gardeners` table twice in the FROM clause.  Use aliases to distinguish the instances in the rest of the query:

```
SELECT gm.managerID "senior gardener"
       , mgr.gardenername
       , gar.gardenername "Manages"
FROM MA_gardenermanager gm
     , MA_gardeners mgr
     , MA_gardeners gar
where mgr.gardenerID = gm.managerID 
and gar.gardenerID = gm.gardenerID
order by gm.managerID
       , gm.gardenerID
```

;

Comment: Genius! This worked perfectly. I have not looked into using aliases as yet so your solution and advise is very gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Because Your Inner Query Return More than 1 Row

Try like this:
Another Way

```
select L.senior_gardener,L.GARDENERNAME,R.Manages from 
(SELECT MA_gardenermanager.managerID "senior gardener"
, MA_gardeners.gardenername
, MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID "Manages"
FROM MA_gardenermanager, MA_gardeners
where MA_gardeners.gardenerID = MA_gardenermanager.managerID
order by MA_gardenermanager.managerID
, MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID
) L
left join (select MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID
, MA_gardeners.gardenername "Manages"
from MA_gardeners, MA_gardenermanager
where MA_gardeners.gardenerID = MA_gardenermanager.gardenerID)R
on L.Manages=R.GARDENERID
```

Comment: I tried this but get the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @TJDMU can you provide fiddle for your data??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by provide fiddle?

Comment: I'll check out fiddle - I tried your edited version but no luck...I get the error  ORA-00904: "L"."MANAGES": invalid identifier.